# Jasmine: How can I reuse other matchers in my custom matchers

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm writing a custom matcher in [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/) (1.3, but the question also applies for 2.0), that extends on the functionality of a built-in matcher. How can I call the built-in matcher *with another actual value*? I've tried to just do `expect(otherActual).toEqual(expected)`, but this returns undefined.

The actual code I've tried:

```
var customMatchers = {
  toHaveAttributes: function (expected) {
    if(!this.actual) {
        throw new Error("Test parameter is " + this.actual);
    }
    if(!(this.actual instanceof Backbone.Model)) {
        throw new Error("Test parameter must be a Backbone Model");
    }
    var notText = this.isNot ? " not" : "";
    var actualAttrs = this.actual.attributes;
    this.message = function () {
        return "Expected model to" + notText + " have attributes " + jasmine.pp(expected) +
        ", but was " + jasmine.pp(actualAttrs);
    };
    // return expect(actualAttrs).toEqual(expected); // Returns undefined
    // return this.env.currentSpec.expect(actualAttrs).toEqual(expected); // Also returns undefined
    return this.env.equals_(actualAttrs, expected); // Works, but copied from jasmine.Matchers.prototype.toEqual
  }
}
```

The matcher is a Backbone-specific shorthand-function to check the attributes of a Model. The two return-lines I've commented out returns undefined. The third return works, but is copy-paste code and uses jasmine internals so is prone to breaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jasmine 2.x at least, factory functions for each registered matcher can be found on the `jasmine.matchers` global object.

To make use of the functionality behind `toEqual` you could write

```
var toEqual = jasmine.matchers.toEqual();
var result = toEqual.compare('foo', 'bar');
```

and in this case value of `result` here would be;

```
{
    pass: false
}
```

because `"foo"` does not equal `"bar"`.